# Is there a global setting in Mapstruct that will trim a string value prior to setting it to a destination bean property

Tags: mapstruct

Is it possible to trim a string value before it is set against a bean property of type string in the destination bean?

Dozer offers such a facility through its mapping configuration for example,

```
<configuration>
    <trim-strings>true</trim-strings>
</configuration>
```

Also see [Dozer Global Configuration](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/globalConfiguration.html)

With MapStruct 1.0.0.Final I can achieve this through [Expressions](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#expressions)  or [Before/After Mapping customization](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after).

But wanted to know if there is a better way to handle such use cases.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It appears MapStruct in its current form does not support this.

However one can achieve this effect with custom mapper methods, for example implement a class with a method that trims a String argument passed to it and then reference this class in the `use` attribute of the `@Mapper` annotation.
More at [Invoking other mappers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#invoking-other-mappers)

If you require fine gained access control you could use 
[Selection based on Qualifiers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#selection-based-on-qualifiers)

I was made aware of these approaches in response to a [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapstruct-users/hsYUvrZ9AJk) I posted in mapstruct Google group

Answer (score 3):

Example from @venkat-srinivasan answer's:

```
public class StringTrimmer {

   public String trimString(String value) {
      return value.trim();
   }
}
```

and then in your mapper interface or class:

```
@Mapper(uses = StringTrimmer.class)
   public interface MyMapper {
```

Comment: return value != null ? value.trim() : null;